# WSO2 Enterprise Store : Calling Services from Javascript

Tags: javascript, wso2, admin, jaggery-js, wso2-es

I'm testing Enterprise Store and managed to invoke Admin Services from custom jaggery file using ws.WSRequest();
Now i'm trybing to do the same with simple javascript code with $ajax calls
I've managed to call 172.27.11.44:9443/admin/services/AuthenticationAdmin/getAuthenticatorName but not succedd with 172.27.11.44:9443/admin/services/AuthenticationAdmin/login, for example
The only diference is on the message payload
Using the following message

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://authentication.services.core.carbon.wso2.org"><soapenv:Body>
<aut:login xmlns:aut="http://authentication.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
<aut:username>admin</aut:username>
<aut:password>admin</aut:password>
</aut:login>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

i got the following error
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException : 3
but the same payload works ok with SOAP UI
Can anyone give light?

Comment: I've managed to put it working using the correct Content Type in the SOAP Message and it runs now (as example) under https://172.27.11.44:9443/store/controllers. But now i want to put it running outside 172.27.11.44:9443 (eg: another site) and i'm having someting like Error: Access is denied. I guess it's because of CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing). Is there any example where i can call from javascript some WSO2 Admin Service outside WSO2?

Comment: Assuming that it's because of CORS, how can i reconfigure WSO2 Services to sent Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the Header?